# Object Oriented In Perl Script

Tags: perl, oop

```
sub new
{
    my $class = shift; #off the first element
    my $self = { };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

Could anyone explain that? What is the use of the following three lines of code?

```
my $self = { };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
```

Comment: These are [OO basics](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

Comment: It returns blessed object (in  this case blessed hash ref).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `my $self = { };` creates an [anonymous hash reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and stores it in [the lexical variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) $self.
2. `bless $self, $class;` tells Perl that $self is not just any reference but actually an object of the class stored in $class. See [bless in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html). `bless $x, $y` returns $x, and a subroutine always returns the value of the last executed statement unless explicetly told otherwise with a `return` statement, so the next line is optional, but good for readability.
3. `return $self;` hands the value in $self (our special object reference) back to the calling function. See [return in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html).

Edit:

To clarify, if you don't `bless` your reference, you won't be able to call methods on it. With `bless` you tell Perl, "look, from now on, associate the reference in $self with the class in $class, so that I can use the methods in that class on the reference."

Comment: suppose if placed `my $self = {
surname => "Galilei",
forename => "Galileo",
address => "9.81 Pisa Apts.",
occupation => "bombadier"
};` instead of `my $self = { };`. What will do this change?

Comment: Creates a hash refererence with those keys and values. I suggest you read up on [hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) and perhaps just all of [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html), as well as the aforementioned [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). Maybe pick up [a book about Perl](http://www.perl.org/books/library.html) or find some good tutorials on [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Tutorials) and [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/tutorials/).

Comment: I got it my comment use . please let me know,the use of @#array ?

Comment: Did you mean $#array? [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types). Really.